# Bootstrap 3 Toggle Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using 2 Bootstrap 3 nav menu in one page. When the menu become responsive(Toggle Menu), One of them working when I click the toggle Button and another doesn't working.
How can I solve this?

Here are the codes of the menus.

**Menu-1:**

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" id="slideTrigger" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> <span>More From Intuit</span></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> +00 000 000 <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

**Menu-2:**

```
<div class="navbar" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse2" data-target=".navbar-collapse2">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" ></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-collapse2 collapse2">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav left_buttons">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Products</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="">DropDown</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">DropDown</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">DropDown</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">DropDown</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">DropDown</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Addons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Checks</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right right_buttons">
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default trial_button">Free Trial</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary signin_button">Sign In</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data-toggle="collapse"`, instead of `data-toggle="collapse2"` on the `button.navbar-toggle` in the second menu.

So `.navbar-collapse2` and `.collapse2` classes are not necessary in `div.navbar-collapse`.

Also add an id to `div.navbar-collapse` and make `data-target` in `button.navbar-toggle` point to this id, instead of class. Even if pointing to the class works ok, it is a good practice to use ids, where possible, cause it points to a native javascript method `getElementById`, instead of jQuery's `$('.class')`. It makes you code works a little bit faster.